# Auth Error {"ErrorCode":"invalid_client","Error":"Client identifier is required"}

Tags: php, authorization

I am trying to login to saleforce api. when I try to login with postman, I can successfully generate the token. But when I tried to login with php CURL .

it is showing

> {"ErrorCode":"invalid_client","Error":"Client identifier is
>   required"}.

```
$header = [
    "Authorization: Basic example_encoded_data",
    "Content-Type: application/json",
];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION,CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use in order to avoid certificate validation:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```